# Visualforce - Make text and formula field graphics the same size

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to make some text and different graphics, that are generated from formula fields, be the same size on a VF page.

What it currently looks like:

[image]

I want everything to be 30px tall. I have tried to add the style class to each outputfield but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is my base code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Employees__c" tabStyle="Employees__c">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Icons Of Guidance"> 
        <apex:outputField value="{!Employees__c.Inactive__c}"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:outputField value="{!Employees__c.In_Window_to_be_Seen__c}"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:outputField value="{!Employees__c.Priority_Code__c}"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:outputField value="{!Employees__c.Age_Yrs__c}"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:outputField value="{!Employees__c.GenderIcon__c}"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:outputField value="{!Employees__c.Verbally_Confirmed_Phone_Update_Age__c  }"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Here is what I have tried to make everything same size:

```
 <apex:page standardController="Employees__c" tabStyle="Employees__c">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Icons Of Guidance"> 
            <apex:outputField value="{!Employees__c.Inactive__c}" style="height:30px;"/>
....
</apex:page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style attribute on outputField only affects the outer span tag. Instead, use the styleClass attribute.

```
<style>
.px30 img {
  height: 30px;
}
</style>

...

<apex:outputField styleClass="px30" value="..." />
```

Note:

I just found this in the docs:

> The style class used to display the output field component, used
>   primarily to designate which CSS styles are applied when using an
>   external CSS stylesheet. This attribute may not work for all values.
>   **If your text requires a class name, use a wrapping span tag**. (Emphasis added).

Apparently, apex:outputField is finicky. I found an alternative structure that does appear to work using the style from above (tested in my dev org):

```
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="px30">
            <apex:outputLabel>{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Image__c.Label}</apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Image__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox but it is not reacting to that either.

Comment: @MattM You may need to resort to an apex:pageBlockSectionItem. Updated with another example.